# New Spreadsheet Row to YouTube Playlist

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube

I have the following code below that takes a new row added to my Google Spreadsheet (has a header row) and extracts the video ID. If the ID does not exist in the playlist, it adds the video to the playlist. If it doesn't, it skips it. Not really comfortable with Google Apps Script, so I would like some constructive feedback.

```
function addVideoToYouTubePlaylist() {
  // retrieve video ID list from the playlist.
  var playlistId = "PL6bCFcS8yqQxSPjwZ9IXFMfVm6kaNGLfi";
  var list = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var res = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list(["snippet"], {playlistId: playlistId, maxResults: 50, pageToken: pageToken});
    if (res.items.length > 0) list = list.concat(res.items);
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken || "";
  } while (pageToken);
  var obj = list.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e.snippet.resourceId.videoId]: e.snippet.resourceId.videoId}), {});

  // read the source videos from Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // iterate through all rows in the sheet
  for (var d=1,l=data.length; d<l; d++) {
    var videoId = extractVideoID(data[d][0]);
    if (!obj[videoId]) {
    YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: {
          kind: "youtube#video",
          videoId: extractVideoID(videoId)
          }
        }
      }, "snippet");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Already in playlist");
    }
    sheet.deleteRow(d+1); // delete row after video is checked
  }
}

function extractVideoID(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if ( match && match[7].length == 11 ){
        return match[7];
    }
    else if (!( match && match[7].length == 11 )){
        console.log("Could not extract video ID.");
        var trimmedVideoID = url.replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace('https://youtube.com/watch?v=', "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=youtu.be", "");
        trimmedVideoID = trimmedVideoID.replace("&feature=share", "");
        console.log(trimmedVideoID);
        return trimmedVideoID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with `extractVideoID()`.

Your regex `/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/` doesn't guarantee the URL has a YouTube format. For example, the URL `www.google.com/watch?v=01$@T$89h` does match the regex and has the following groups: `["www.google.com/watch?v=0123456", "watch?", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "watch?", "01$@T$89h"]`, where the 7th group `01$@T$89h` isn't a valid YouTube video ID.

I suggest you replace your regex with `/^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/` ([source](https://regexr.com/3dj5t)). This regex only matches valid YouTube URLs format, and the 5th group is the ID of the video. Notice that a valid YouTube URL along with a video ID **doesn't guarantee that the video exist**. You can use [`YouTube.Videos.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to test if the video for the given ID exists.

```
  if ( match && match[7].length == 11 ){
    return match[7];
  }
  else if (!( match && match[7].length == 11 )){ // equivalent of else {}
    // multiple attempts to replace
    return trimmedVideoID;
  }
```

The `if..else if` block is bad. If you find a match, you return the ID. Done. So `extractVideoID()` has only one purpose: if the URL has a valid format, return the ID. Otherwise, i.e., if it doesn't find a match, then `extractVideoID()` should return `null`.

```
if (match && match[5])
  return match[5];
```

In your code, the `else if` block is opposite of the first `if`, so it is actually an `else` block. This also means that, altought you couldn't find any match, you are returning anything anyway, even if `url` is garbage like `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`.

Now, with `addVideoToYouTubePlaylist()`.

`pageToken = res.nextPageToken || "";`

The `nextPageToken` is a string for the next page, so unless `YouTube.PlaylistItems.list()` fails - and thow an error, stopping everything - it won't evaluate to false. And if it does, you are restarting all over again, possibly heading to the same `falsy` value thus creating an infinite loop.

`for (var d=1,l=data.length; d<l; d++) {`

You can test `d < data.length` directly for improved reading.

```
  var videoId = extractVideoID(data[d][0]);
  if (!obj[videoId]) {
  YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
```

You may want to test if the video with the given ID exists before of inserting it in the playlist.

```
  resourceId: {
    kind: "youtube#video",
    videoId: extractVideoID(videoId)
  }
```

Without chaning `extractVideoID()` and passing a valid ID to it returns `null`.

`sheet.deleteRow(d+1); // delete row after video is checked`

When you delete row number `d+1`, what was in row `(d+1)+1` now is in row `d+1`. Because of that, you need a counter of deleted rows, say `r`, and delete the row number `d+1-r` to compensate the upward "shift".

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation of everything. However, I'm having a hard time putting all this together. Do you think you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should start with `extractVideoID()` for it to test the url with the regex from the answer to test if there is a match and the match also has an id, i.e., the 5th group is not empty. Otherwise, don't return anything and move forward to the next url.